# What is the name of 'scalars' and empty variables in linear/affine equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear equation of form $y = S \cdot X$ for example:

$$ y = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
3 \\
\frac{3}{4}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} $$

- How is set $\left\{x_1, x_3, x_4\right\}$ called (i.e. non-zero component)?
- How is set $\left\{x_2\right\}$ called (it is still in vector space of linear equations)?
- How can I call function $\left\{x_1 \to 1, x_2 \to 0, x_3 \to 3, x_4 \to \frac{3}{4}\right\}$ (essentially $f(x) = S \cdot x$ but with $x$ restricted to base vectors)?

Comment: What you’ve written isn’t even an equation.

Comment: @amd fixed though I'd assume that it would be understandable notation?

Comment: So, how do you define the product of a pair of column vectors?

Comment: @amd As [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)? $ (\sum_{i = 0}^n x_i\hat{e_i}) \cdot (\sum_{i = 0}^n y_i\hat{e_i}) = \sum_{i = 0}^n x_iy_i$ or $x \cdot y = x^Ty$. Sorry if notation is confusing - I though it was clear enough ($X$ is vector of variables, $S$ is vector of constants).

Comment: It's very unusual; in coordinates, it's nearly universal to take the 'equations' (i.e. the coefficients for the linear combination) from a space of *row* vectors, and the "variable vector" comes from a space of *column* vectors, and they're combined by the ordinary matrix product. (in a coordinate-free algebra, the 'equations' are covectors, not vectors)

Comment: @Hurkyl Yeah I always seen the written as as $y = Ax$. I just rearranged $A$ without thinking as it is a single equation. I didn't thought it would cause confusion (unfortunately my linear algebra classes were some time ago and while I retain general understanding, details of rigor were lost).